# How to get first 25 characters from Long string value and also show the full value in tool tip in MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi i want to know how to get first 25 characters from Long string value. Example i have string value like 
"Clamp-on Injection probe Instrumentation" now i want to get the first 25 characters from this string.And also i want to show the whole string value in Tool Tip.

My code

```
string val1 ="Clamp-on Injection probe Instrumentation"
 string val2 =val1.Substring(25, Math.Min(val1 .Length, maxLength));
```

I have tried the above code.And correct my code if i am wrong and also tell me how to show the whole string value in tool tip .Kindly any one help me resolve this issue.Thanks.

Comment: Per MSDN's docs for [Substring(int, int)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_), you are using Substring wrong. The first argument is the index at which you want to _start_ getting characters, and the 2nd is the length. If you want to get only the first 25 characters, you need this: `val1.Substring(0, Math.Min(val1.Length, 25));`. As to the rest, please provide any code samples you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Below code should get you first 25 characters of string :

```
string val1 = "Clamp-on Injection probe Instrumentation";
string val2 = val1.Substring(0, 25);
```

In your html:

```
@Html.Label("Your label string ",new { title="tooltip string"});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using just CSS would do it, try building a html like this:

```
<h4 title="Clamp-on Injection probe Instrumentation">
    Clamp-on Injection probe Instrumentation
</h4>
```

And add this kind of CSS:

```
h4{
  width: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This would make the text that doesn't fit within 50px to be hidden using ellipsis `...`, and will show the full tooltip since the `title` contains the full text.

Hope it helps.